# FPDF add-on "Write-Html-Tables" with multicell support / line breaks in cell

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I use the FPDF add-on "write-html-tables". The add-on works really good with HTML tables.

http://fpdf.de/downloads/add-ons/write-html-tables.html

But I have a problem with line breaks. If the content of a cell is too long, I can't make a line break inside the cell and the text overlaps the next cell.

I tried to extend the code from the "write-html-tables" add-on but it doesn't work. Does anyone have a tip for me how can I expand the add-on?

Comment: Have you tried the `<br>` tag in the cell?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the <br> tag generates a completely new cell under the cell with the <br> and the structure of the table is not correct anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that FPDF Add-on Write-Html-Tables has mistakes with new lines in a table cell. I checked it with `\n` and `<br>` – the same mistake.

**Recommended solution**

If you are using HTML code to build tables for PDF documents generated with the FPDF library, then I would like to recommend the [FPDF easyTable project (FPDF Add-on)](https://github.com/fpdf-easytable/fpdf-easytable).

You have to download `easyTable.php`, `formatedstring.php`, `exfpdf.php` from this project and to save this files in the FPDF folder. Do not forget to delete all symbols after `?>` on the end of your PHP files.

**Example:**

```php
<?php
include 'fpdf.php';
include 'exfpdf.php';
include 'easyTable.php';

$pdf = new exFPDF();
$pdf->AddPage(); 
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica','',10);

$table = new easyTable($pdf, '%{70,30}', 'border:1');

$table->easyCell('If the content of a cell is too long, I can make a line break inside the cell and the text does not overlap the next cell.', 'colspan:2; bgcolor:#b3ccff');
$table->printRow();

$table->easyCell('If the content of a cell is too long, I can make a line break inside the cell and the text does not overlap the next cell.');
$table->easyCell('Some values 1');
$table->printRow();

//the next line is double quoted because new line(\n) should be interpreted
$table->easyCell("If the content of a cell is too long, I can make a line break inside the cell and\n\nthe text does not overlap the next cell.");
$table->easyCell('Some values 2');
$table->printRow();

$table->endTable(5);

$pdf->Output();
?>
```

**Output example as part of screenshot:**

[image: fpdf easytable example]

If you want break lines manually, then you should use double quotes `"` around your `\n` instead of single quotes `'`.

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

> The simplest way to specify a string is to enclose it in single quotes
>   (the character `'`).
>
> To specify a literal single quote, escape it with a backslash (`\`).
>   To specify a literal backslash, double it (`\\`). All other instances
>   of backslash will be treated as a literal backslash: this means that
>   the other escape sequences you might be used to, such as `\r` or `\n`,
>   will be output literally as specified rather than having any special
>   meaning.

If the string is enclosed in double-quotes (`"`), PHP will interpret [escape sequences such as `\n`].